# Animated Fur can't use texture, like the rest of the body

Tags: animation, texturing, particles

[image: Screenshot]

If you llok at the UV image editor you see the white area top right. This is supposed to be the snout's color. But in the 3D-view it is black. I found out, that blender uses only the pixels from the edge of the texture to colour the whole Vertex group, that defines the shorter hair of the face. These are animated as theRender panel shows. They grow. Also the Hair dynamics are baked as you can see in the timeline. The image texture works, as you can see from the body, so i assume that this is a bug. Or does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that i emitted the hair from vertices. That's why the hair only used the colour information of the corners of the texture. The image information is in the faces so make sure to select faces instead of verts in the emitter panel of the particles tab.